# How to add a document class to TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, document-classes

I want to add a new document class to TexStudio. The document class is named "AEA" and is available in [this link](http://www.aeaweb.org/aer/submissions.php) (the first .zip file below "Please note:")

The code will look like this

```
\documentclass[AER]{AEA}
\draftSpacing{1.5}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Extract the zip file, open the `*-Article.tex file` where `*` is AER or AEJ or JRL as per your choice and use it to type your paper. It should work.

Comment: I already have done that. TeXstudio does not find the package "AEA". when I put the pointer of my mouse on "AEA" word, it writes "package not found".

Comment: If AEA.cla is in the same folder as your .tex file then it should work. If not, more details may be needed.

Comment: Note, that the "package not found" message is from a TXS internal scanner. It currently only searches the standard tex folders not the local folder. It's merely a hint, but does not reflect a result from a latex call. So if your compilation works fine, you can ignore that message (or swith off the package scanner at Options -> Editor -> Inline Checking -> Package.)

Answer (score 5):

TXS uses an internal scanner to detect packages and classes. It currently only searches the standard tex folders not the local folder.

If the internal parser cannot locate the file (maybe because it's in the local folder), the package or class name are highlighted in the editor and the toolitp says "package not found". This is merely a hint. It does not reflect a result from a latex call.

So if your compilation works fine, you can ignore that message (or swith off the package scanner at Options -> Editor -> Inline Checking -> Package.)

Comment: "t currently only searches the standard tex folders not the local folder. " Is it still the case in the latest version 2.12.16?